# Errai JAX-RS - No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I'm having issue on Errai Jax-rs, I'm not sure why this would not work:

```
@Path("userservice")
public interface UserService {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void login(LoginForm login);
}
```

And when called from the UI:

```
    service.call(new RemoteCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(Void response) {
                         // Do stuff        
        }
    }, new ErrorCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean error(Message message, Throwable throwable) {
            return false;
        }
    }).login(new LoginForm(this.username.getText(),
            this.password.getText(),
            true));
```

Throws this error:

```
[INFO] DEBUG [SynchronousDispatcher] PathInfo: /userservice
[INFO] DEBUG [ExceptionHandler] Failed executing POST /userservice
[INFO] org.jboss.resteasy.spi.MethodNotAllowedException: No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.Segment.match(Segment.java:112)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.PathParamSegment.matchPattern(PathParamSegment.java:200)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchChildren(RootSegment.java:339)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:374)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootSegment.matchRoot(RootSegment.java:367)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:354)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:231)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:170)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
[INFO]  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
[INFO]  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:39)
[INFO]  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
[INFO]  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
[INFO]  at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
[INFO]  at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
[INFO]  at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
[INFO]  at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
[INFO]  at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
[INFO]  at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
[INFO]  at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
[INFO]  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
[INFO]  at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
[INFO]  at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
[INFO]  at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:438)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can have a `void` return type in JAX-RS? (BTW, nothing to do with Errai here, it's JAX-RS on the server-side, using Resteasy as the implementation)

Comment: Yes, @Override public void login(LoginForm login) { }

Comment: No, I meant, does JAX-RS (JSR 311 / JSR 339), and incidentally Resteasy, allows a resource method to have a return type of `void`? I checked the spec and it's allowed (will map to an HTTP 204 status code); so it's not the issue here.

Comment: Does your implementation of UserService change the `@Consumes` or `@Produces` content types of the login() method? Does it override the `@Path` value, either at the class or method level?

Comment: @JonathanFuerth, No I don't think so, as the annotations are on the interface only

Comment: I attempted to reproduce the problem locally. I thought it might be the `@Produces` annotation on the `void` method that was causing the problem. But even with `@Consumes("application/json") @Produces("application/json") @POST public void postMe(PortableType arg)`, RestEasy was routing the POST request to the method properly. This is kind of a "works for me" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same Exception when trying to access a Service via RestEasy. So in case someone else stumbles upon it:

as Andreas already mentioned, it often refers to a wrong URL.

In my case i could call my Service via Postman or the resteasy target with

```
final String path = "http://localhost:8080/repository/user";
```

e.g.

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/repository/user");
        Response response = target.request().get();
```

while using a Resteasy-Proxy i had to use

```
final String path = "http://localhost:8080/repository";
```

e.g.

```
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:8080/repository"));
    IUserTestRepository proxy = target.proxy(IUserTestRepository.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

This error typically occurs because the rest/endpoint address is not available:

1. Check the *@Path* annotation above the class name
2. Check the *@Path* annotation above the method name
3. If you are using *@PathParam* or *@QueryParam* annotations make sure two things:

   - The value corresponds to the declared type in the method signature
   - Check if you are passing the right number of params
   - All annotations imports are actually from package **javax.ws.rs**

If the error persists, try to check your CORS implementation, if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when trying to access my method with wrong number of parameters.

I called: `http://localhost:8080/my-app/my-service/param1`

whereas the service was expecting: `http://localhost:8080/my-app/my-service/param1/param2`